# form processing a radio button in php

Tags: php, email, radio-button, return-value, processing

I have an rsvp form that I am trying to send the value of a radio button but unsure of the php for it, my code is as follows:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" placeholder="Name(s)" class="text-input form-control" />
     <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">Name is required.</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <input type="radio" name="response" id="response_accepted" value="accepted" checked="checked" > Will be there
     <input type="radio" name="response" id="response_declined" value="declined"> Won't make it
     <label class="error" for="response" id="name_error">Please select an option</label>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="guests" id="guests" size="30" value="" placeholder="No. of guests attending" class="text-input form-control" />
     <label class="error" for="guests" id="guests_error">No. of guests is required.</label>
</div>
```

but i'm not sure of the php that collects the value of the radio button but have got the other fields to pass the data using:

```
    <?php
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0)) {
    $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
} else {$name = 'No name entered';}

if ((isset($_POST['guests'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['guests'])) > 0)) {
    $guests = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['guests']));
} else {$guests = 'No # of guests entered';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will process in the same way as the other, the only difference is that you already know its value, so you will need to

```
if ((isset($_POST['response'])) && ($_POST['response'] == 'accepted' ) {
    $response = 'Accepted';
} else {$response= 'Not Accepted';}
```

Comment: +1 for checking isset(). Keep in mind if your radio button is checked only then you will get the value. If it is left unchecked, you need to set the response manually as radio button won't be passed in request in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you

```
$response = $_POST['response'] ; 

if(isset($response) && $resonse == "accepted" )){ 
echo "Accepted" ; 
}
else{ echo "Declined" ;  }
```